# Laravel / Eloquent model with custom relations

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Imagine:

I have a adverts table with a price column.
I have a pricerange table with a price_from and a price_to column.

I want to setup my Eloquent models, so that I can fetch the matching adverts from a Pricerange instance. Or query the pricerange table, and do a count on all matching adverts. Optionally, get the query from the adverts-relation and add more criteria.

In other words, I'd like the equivalent of this raw query:

```
SELECT priceranges.*, (
  SELECT COUNT(adverts.id) FROM adverts
  WHERE adverts.price >= priceranges.price_from 
  AND adverts.price < priceranges.price_to 
) AS adverts_count
FROM priceranges
```

or

```
SELECT priceranges.*, COUNT(adverts.id) AS adverts_count
FROM priceranges
INNER JOIN adverts ON adverts.price >= priceranges.price_from 
AND adverts.price < priceranges.price_to 
GROUP BY priceranges.id
```

Is this possible? I searched on custom relations, but I cannot find a working solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's something a bit strange with your data model. Eloquent can't really help you but you might have some more success with the query builder if you convert your query to a `JOIN` e.g. `priceranges p JOIN adverts a ON (a.price >= p.price_from AND a.price < p.price_to)` that way it's more natural to write it as a query builder query.

Comment: Yes, but I cannot define this join relation in a eloquent model?

Comment: I don't think so. Eloquent relationships rely heavily on foreign keys but you don't have any here. You can create a [scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#query-scopes) though

Comment: thanks, will look into this, it looks like this maybe is a solution

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```
Priceranges::join('adverts',function($join){
  $join->on('adverts.price','>=','priceranges.price_from')->orOn('adverts.price','<','priceranges.price_to');
})
->groupBy('priceranges.id')
->get();
```